# Probability density function good example

Tags: probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

Even though a fast-food chain might advertise a hamburger as weighing a quarter-pound, you can well imagine that it is not exactly 0.25 pounds. One randomly selected hamburger might weigh 0.23 pounds while another might weigh 0.27 pounds.  What is the probability that a randomly selected hamburger weighs between 0.20 and 0.30 pounds? That is, if we let X denote the weight of a randomly selected quarter-pound hamburger in pounds, what is P(0.20 < X < 0.30)?

Comment: Another question: What do you mean when you say that "Euclidean circle in the hyperbolic plane"? How can you draw an Euclidean circle in the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: Why did you not tell that you were having in mind the upper half plane model. The whole question is meaningless without nailing down a model in which  the concept of an Euclidean circle is meaningful. Also, If you have the upper half plane model then where is the center of the hyperbolic plane. Do you know that the hyperbolic plane does not have a center?

Comment: I would take it to mean that at the points where they intersect they are orthogonal.

Comment: @Cristiane Zeitlin Is there a text-book/source that mentions this  proposition?

Answer (score 1):

This is an absolute statement:

> *If a line is perpendicular to a circle (it is perpendicular to the tangents through its intersection points) then that line will go through the center of the circle. This statement does not depend on the postulate of parallelism.*

So, the statement does not have anything to do with the Poincaré disk or half plane model. The statement will be true in any model of the hyperbolic or the Euclidean plane.

Having understood this, one may ask questions about the different intuitions of the same statement in different models of the hyperbolic plane.

For instance, in the Klein model, this is how to intuit the statement

[image]

Here, the green curve is the edge of the Klein model. The black line is perpendicular to the red tangents, that is to the circle.

Below, our absolute statement is shown in the usual model of the Euclidean geometry:

[image]

Finally, this is the visualization in the Poincaré disk model

[image]

The misleading specialty of the Poincare models (half plane and disk) is that the circles look Euclidean circles...

But, behind all these pictures there is a very simple absolute statement quoted above.

Answer (score 0):

It can be ordered in a wider context using bipolar coordinates in the complex plane for hyperbolic geodesics, where  $ \tau = const $ and $\sigma =const $ orthogonal circles being real and imaginary parts of a single complex variable

$$ w= \tau +i \sigma\,; \,z= a \coth(w/2)\,; $$

inside the " Poincaré compounded " model. I present here a comprehensive/integrated  picture of the two Poincaré models as follows :

Under this re-arrangement we consider a hyperbolic geodesic line $L$ in the Poincaré plane model  and let $C$ be a euclidean circle *set* contained in the hyperbolic plane.  We can see that $L$ is perpendicular to euclidean circle set $C$ invariably (if and only if) $L$ passes through the hyperbolic centre of $C$, viz., center of concurrency $O$. The euclidean circles are non-concentric,  from centre offset retaining a constant tangent length from the fixed central pole on real axis.

The point of concurrecy is a singular solution for set of circles $L,C$. In this sense they have been already termed as "foci" in Wikipaedia cited.

It is seen that this compounded model addresses the given question in title by integrating the Poincaré plane & disc models. In either case red $L$ circles are  hyperbolic geodesics and *interstingly placed* blue euclidean $C$ circles **to pass through a single focal point as hyperbolic center** $O$ and its conjugate with powers $\pm a^2$.If $O$ has coordinates $(0,a)$ then the $L$ circle set has *power* $- a^2$ and likewise the $C$ circles set has *power* $+a^2, $ corrosponding to $\tau \rightarrow \infty. $

[Compound "Poincaré disk + plane" models](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollonian_circles.svg)

[Wiki Bipolar Cordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates)

[image]